# Is there an updated Cataclysm flight path/travel map anywhere?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I've been searching for a map of griffin/boat/zeppelin travel routes for Kalimdor and Eastern Kingdoms that has been updated since Cataclysm, but all I've found using Google are out-of-date maps from years ago.  I'm particularly interested in Alliance routes, but a complete map for both factions would be nice too. Can anyone provide a link to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wowhead shows flight paths and travel routes on continent maps.

- **Eastern Kingdoms** - [Alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=0#show:alliance:flightmaster) - [Horde](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=0#show:horde:flightmaster)
- **Kalimdor** - [Alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=1#show:alliance:flightmaster) - [Horde](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=1#show:horde:flightmaster)
- **Outland** - [Alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=8#show:alliance:flightmaster) - [Horde](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=8#show:horde:flightmaster)
- **Northrend** - [Alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=10#show:alliance:flightmaster) - [Horde](http://www.wowhead.com/zones=10#show:horde:flightmaster)

Comment: These don't show flight paths.

Comment: Hmm, the markdown renderer is mangling the URLs. There are supposed to be colons in there...

Comment: Seems like it's a [bug in the Markdown renderer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88641/colons-in-hashtag-portion-of-url-are-improperly-encoded).

Comment: Actually looks like a bug in Wowhead's code. %3a is the proper encoding of the colon; Wowhead should be urldecoding before interpreting the request.

Answer (score 5):

**Alliance:**

[Eastern Kingdom](http://www.wowpedia.org/File:Cata_Alliance_EK_flights.jpg)

[Kalimdor](http://www.wowpedia.org/File:Cata_Alliance_Kali_flights.jpg)

**Horde:**

[Eastern Kingdom](http://www.wowpedia.org/File:Cata_Horde_Eastern_Kingdoms_flights.jpg)

[Kalimdor](http://www.wowpedia.org/File:Cata_Horde_Kalimdor_flights.jpg)

Comment: -1 These maps aren't very good, unlabelled and some of them aren't even connected.

Comment: +1 @mordi2k- You answer 1/3 of the question. The body of the question asked for griffin, boat, and zeppelin. Not just for the griffin as you answered.  (+1 @lol and +mordi2k)

Answer (score 2):

Wowpedia have an updated travel guide for the new expansion.

Includes some maps - which may be of help

http://www.wowpedia.org/Cataclysm_travel_guide